# Inverse of $2I_n+J+J^T$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix, $J$ is a upper triangular matrix with entries $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Inverse of $2I_n+J+J^T$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix, $J$ is a upper triangular matrix with entries $1$, $J=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&&\\
&\ddots&\ddots&\\
&&\ddots&1\\
&&&0\end{pmatrix}$

Is there any easy method? I found the tri-diagonal matrix. But it is quite hard to follow. For such a matrix, the inverse can be easily calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the matrix
$$
A=(I-J)(I-J)^T=\pmatrix{2&-1\\ -1&\ddots&\ddots\\ &\ddots&2&-1\\ &&-1&1}
$$
first. Since $J$ is nilpotent, $(I-J)^{-1}$ is equal to $U:=I+J+J^2+\cdots+J^{n-1}$, which is the upper triangular matrix of ones. Therefore
\begin{aligned}
A^{-1}
=U^TU
=\pmatrix{1&1&1&\cdots&1\\ 1&2&2&\cdots&2\\ 1&2&3&\cdots&3\\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\1&2&3&\cdots&n}
=\big(\min\{i,j\}\big)_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}.
\end{aligned}
Now, note that
$$
B=\pmatrix{2&-1\\ -1&\ddots&\ddots\\ &\ddots&2&-1\\ &&-1&2}=A+e_ne_n^T
$$
is a rank-one update of $A$. Let $u=A^{-1}e_n=(1,2,\ldots,n)^T$. By [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula),
\begin{aligned}
B^{-1}
&=A^{-1}-\frac{A^{-1}e_ne_n^TA^{-1}}{1+e_n^TA^{-1}e_n}\\
&=A^{-1}-\frac{uu^T}{n+1}\\
&=\left(\min\{i,j\}-\frac{ij}{n+1}\right)_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,\}}.\\
\end{aligned}
Finally, let $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1,1,-1,\ldots,(-1)^{n-1})$. Since $D=D^{-1}$ and $2I+J+J^T=DBD$, we have
$$
(2I+J+J^T)^{-1}=DB^{-1}D
=\left((-1)^{i+j}\left(\min\{i,j\}-\frac{ij}{n+1}\right)\right)_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,\}}.
$$